# How do I call the original "operator new" if I have overloaded it?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, operator-overloading

Suppose I need to overload global `::operator new()` [for storing extra data with each allocated object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068046/getting-to-know-size-of-a-reserved-memory-on-the-heap/4068118#4068118). So basically it would work this way:

- for each call to global `::operator new()` it will take the object size passed and add the size of extra data
- it will *allocate a memory block* of size deduced at previous step
- it will offset the pointer to the part of the block not occupied with extra data and return that offset value to the caller

`::operator delete()` will do the same in reverse - shift the pointer, access extra data, deallocate memory.

Now the question is *how do I allocate memory*? Of course I can call `malloc()` or some platform-specific function (that's how it is usually done). But normally when I need to allocate raw memory in C++ I call `::operator new()`. Can I call the original `::operator new()` to do the memory allocation from inside my overloaded global `::operator new()`?

Comment: Do you mean overloaded or replaced? If overloaded, just call the original operator new by using the correct set of arguments. If replaced, then no you can't but I believe this is _why_ `malloc` is guaranteed not to use `operator new` in its implementation (i.e. no unintentional loops when operator new is replaced) so you probably should be using `malloc`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey You wrote your answer as a comment! for shame!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't access them because it isn't really overloading, it's replacement. When you define your own `::operator new`, the old one goes away. That's pretty much that.

Essentially, you need to call `malloc` from a custom `::operator new`. Not only that, but also follow the directions in 18.4.1.1/4 to properly handle errors:

> Default behavior:
>
> — Executes a loop:
> Within the loop, the function first
> attempts to allocate the requested
> storage. Whether the attempt involves
> a call to the Standard C library
> function malloc is unspecified.
>
> —
> Returns a pointer to the allocated
> storage if the attempt is successful.
> Otherwise, if the last argument to
> set_new_handler() was a null pointer,
> throw bad_alloc.
>
> — Otherwise, the
> function calls the current new_handler
> (18.4.2.2). If the called function
> returns, the loop repeats.
>
> — The loop
> terminates when an attempt to allocate
> the requested storage is successful or
> when a called new_handler function
> does not return.

Comment: And don't forget to replace `operator delete` too, with `free()`.

Comment: I believe Scott Meyers talks about this in detail in on of his _Effective C++_ books. Item 8 in the second edition, and chapter 8 in the 3rd, as it seems.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Couldn't he use `malloc()` to allocate the memory for his class and extra data and then call `placement-new` to instantiate the class object within this memory. Since he's only replacing the regular version of `new` wouldn't the default `placement-new` be called?

Comment: @Praetorian: That will work, but this will force me to handle all error handling myself. For example - what if the constructor throws?

Comment: @Sharptooth: You can have everything in a `try-catch` block, cleanup the allocated memory and rethrow the exception.

Comment: @sharptooth: Why do you think that you need to worry about the constructor throwing? If you replace `operator new` and `operator delete` the implementation will ensure that your replaced `operator delete` will be called if the constructor of an object throws after you've successfully returned a pointer to allocated memory for the object from your replaced `operator new`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Yes, sure, but only if I use a new-statement. User Praetorian seems to suggest that I allocate memory and then call the constructor in-place (via placement new). In this case C++ won't take care of memory deallocation.

Comment: @sharptooth: OK, I looks like I didn't fully understand what Praetorian was suggesting.