# How could I prohibit use of "new" in certain parts of C++ code?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator

Is it possible to prevent new from being used at certain points in the code?

The legacy code that I am developing with has a requirement that there is no dynamic memory allocation after the bootstrap has completed. We now want to test this.

If I was starting the development from scratch then I could write my own wrapper and use that, or overload operator new in a common base class.

Is there a way of overloading global new and then calling it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't "overload" global `new` - [only replace it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4134195/57428). However in your replacement you can check for a global flag meaning "new allowed" (and throw an exception if that flag is not set) and change that flag from inside calling code. This won't help against overloaded `operator new` in classes unless you change each overload to also respect that flag.

Comment: Good, that sounds like what I was thinking of. Do I then need to use malloc to allocate the memory? Will this call the class constructor?

Comment: @DanS: `operator new()` only allocates memory - C++ will then call the constructor. See this answer on how to implement `operator new()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134195/how-do-i-call-the-original-operator-new-if-i-have-overloaded-it/4134355#4134355

Comment: @DanS You need to use something other than `operator new` to allocate the memory, and `malloc` is as good as anything else.  Note too that if you replace `operator new`, you need to replace `operator delete` as well; if you're using `malloc` to allocate memory, you need to be sure that `operator delete` is using `free`, and not something else.  (Although from what you describe, I wouldn't be surprised if an `operator delete` that just aborts wouldn't be appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

Not ***Overloading*** but ***Replacing*** new globally is indeed possible.

The C++ standard has set of predefined new and delete operators. The most commonly used versions are:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc); 
void  operator delete(void*) throw(); 
void* operator new[](std::size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc);  
void  operator delete[](void*) throw();
```

The first two versions allocate & deallocate memory for an object, the last two are for  array of objects.

If you provide own versions of these is called ***replacing***  the ones from the standard library.

If you overload operator `new`, you should always also overload the matching operator `delete`, even if will be never called or used by you.

Comment: Note that according to the standard, the default `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` must forward directly to `operator new` and `operator delete`, so you don't need to replace these unless you want them to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably try:

```
#define new new(your imagination)
```

and later undefine it
depends on your situation

Comment: The 2 solutions from 2 years ago are much better ideas, if only because they don't break placement new.

Comment: use "your imagination", dont break things ;)

Comment: That won't help a bit. Placement new looks like `new (here) Type`. There can be exactly one `()` argument list between `new` and `Type`. Your macro invariably adds that, so it always breaks if another argument list is present. Literally, you can't come up with a single counter-example.