# Is this way to allocate memory bad?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was wonder how `malloc` would allocate memory (can you tell me ?), so I tried something.

Is this a bad way to allocate memory ?

```
void* myMalloc(unsigned int size) {
    return (void*) new bool[size];
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that a bool occupies more space than a single byte? Or to be more accurate, there's nothing that says it *must* be one byte. The amount of actual memory this allocates may change on other architectures or compilers. This is very bad.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but usually, `new` calls `malloc` (or goes straight to whatever lower-level function the default `malloc` is a wrapper for), not the other way around.

Comment: So what's so bad about `malloc` anyway that makes you want to do this?

Comment: @Stargazer712 I think the OP is under the assumption that `malloc` invokes `new`.

Comment: The `size` parameter should be of type `size_t`, and the `new` expression should be `new char[size]`.

Comment: your "Malloc" isn't a `malloc`, it's a `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to disagree with *quite* so many people recommending that you use `new char[n]`, but I feel obliged to do so.

Since you want to allocate "raw" memory, not objects, you should really use `::operator new` instead of `new some_type[some_size]`:

```
 void *myMalloc(size_t size) { 
     return ::operator new(size);
 }
```

Ultimately, `new char[whatever]` isn't particularly harmful, but (at least IMO) it's conceptually wrong, and I see no advantage over using `::operator new` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. Can you tell me, When **::operator new** uses *malloc()*, what uses malloc then ?

Comment: `malloc` will normally use something supplied by the underlying OS such as `brk` (or `sbrk`) on Unix, `HeapAlloc` on Windows, etc. Also note that while *early* implementations of C++ often implemented `::operator new` by calling `malloc`, on a modern system, it'll probably go directly to the OS as well.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard states explicitely that the C `malloc` and `free` functions must not call `operator new` or `operator delete` (20.6.13/3 and 4 in the C++11 FDIS). This makes a red light blink in my mind...

Aside from that, your approach dumps all type-safety `new` could give you that `malloc` lacks. And your implementation will be too slow for what it does.

Conclusion: yes, this is a bad way to allocate memory.

Comment: can you please quote the standard?

Comment: -1 The standard says malloc and free do not **attempt** to call new or delete. That's quite different than "must not call". That wouldn't even make sense since they're built-in functions, so you couldn't possibly modify how they work.

Comment: Luchian: I think you misunderstand my point. The C functions made available in C++ `malloc` and `free` will not attempt, ergo will not call C++'s `new` or `delete`. That's why I said it's probably a bad idea to define a user-made malloc that uses `new`.

Comment: I completely agree that it's a bad idea. I also understood your point but you can also make a point without miss-quoting the standard.

Comment: Luchian: I could hardly just say "calling new from a malloc is bad" without any form of precedent or argumentation. I just used the first argument that came into my mind, which is quite compelling IMHO...

Comment: "The C++ standard states explicitely that the C malloc and free functions must not call operator new or operator delete" - this is not an argument - this is simply a FALSE statement, as the C++ standard states no such thing. Also "calling new from a malloc" is also wrong, since there is only ONE malloc. Please understand that I agree that it's wrong to do it, I don't advise it, however I am in disagreement with your argument for the sheer fact that it's misleading - which it is.

Comment: Luchian: The community disagrees with your interpretation (see point 7 in the malloc/free half of the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free/240308#240308

Answer (score 4):

The are some mistakes:

1) you're assuming `sizeof(bool) == 1`, which is not necessarily true. Change the

```
return (void*) new bool[size];
```

to

```
return (void*) new char[size];
```

2) how will you free the memory? You'd have to do something like:

```
char* x = myMalloc(unsigned int size);
delete[] x; //not free, since you actually use new and not malloc
```

3) `malloc` doesn't call `new`, it's probably the other way around (in VS20xx new will call `malloc`). `malloc` also doesn't call the constructors, so if this does work, it will only work for basic types.

Comment: How do you know that `new` calls `malloc()`?

Comment: We [discussed this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443782/does-dynamic-memory-allocation-differ-in-c-and-c-in-popular-implementations) a while ago, and it seems that all popular platforms implement `::operator new()` in terms of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()`/`free()` is not necessarily compatible with `new` and `delete`.  `new` might very well invoke `malloc()` (at least by default), but you shouldn't count on it.

One major difference between `malloc()` and `new()` is that `malloc()` returns a `void*` that points to raw memory, whereas `new` returns a typed pointer and calls the constructor, if any (and `delete` calls the destructor).

If you're writing C++, there is very rarely a good reason to allocate raw untyped memory.

But if you really want to do so, you can write something like:

```
void *p = (void*)new char[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate a certain number of bytes with `new[]`, use `new char[n]`. Unlike `bool`, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

As to implementation of `new` and `malloc`, `new` is a higher-level construct (as it also calls constructors for types that have those), and therefore likely implemented in terms of `malloc`, not the other way round.