# Converting malloc to new

Tags: c++, c

I am compiling using g++.  This is valid but I want to convert to the C++ operators new() and delete() because this is considered best practice.

```
  int *scratch = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  free(scratch);
```

What is the equivalent using new and delete?  This is my guess.

```
 int **scratch = new int*[size];
 delete[] scratch;
```

This is for an array of pointers.

The double star is a reference.  It is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: A reference and a pointer to a pointer are _very_ different things.

Comment: Your link is broken.  A pointer is close to a reference.  So a pointer to a pointer is close (conceptually) to a reference to a pointer.  But either way they're used differently, with different limitations, and different syntax.

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts your code: It is indeed true that `::operator new()` is the C++ analogue of `malloc()`, and the former is in fact almost [universally implemented by the latter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443782/does-dynamic-memory-allocation-differ-in-c-and-c-in-popular-implementations). However, what you're using in the code is the `new` **expression**`, which is a different animal entirely (as it has something to do with constructors).

Comment: Maybe conceptually (although that concept would be a really mysterious one), but it is definitely not equivalent to your `malloc` example. C'mon you already know how pointers work, they're not any different in C++. And I don't know what reference you are talking about, but I never heard somebody call a pointer to pointer a reference, at least not in C++, where the word reference has an entirely different meaning, anyway.

Comment: Search for reference here... http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf - this is not broken..a reference is a pointer to a pointer....but syntactically they are different

Comment: new and delete are C++ operators while malloc and calloc are functions frequently used to implement new and delete

Comment: The 4 people that upvoted Mooing Duck are flat wrong...they are not very different things

Comment: My guess is that pre-C++ a pointer to a pointer was called a reference...when C++ implmented this with the &...this concept was lost too most, as it was no longer expressed explicitly.  What do you all think a reference is in terms of data and addresses?

Comment: @ChrisAaker No you're plain wrong! You cannot just generalize from the linked paper terminology. In the words of this paper, you can call a pointer to a pointer a reference **to a pointer**, depending on the context (in this case function parameters), and not just a reference in general. That's what they all complain about, with right. But even then in your example it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Christian..O.K what is a refence than? Other than the syntax &...what is it?

Comment: @ChrisAaker Conceptually, a reference is an alias to another variable. Practically, a C++ reference is a pointer without some of the pointer functionality (artihmetic, repointing). But even in a very general language-agnostic terminology, your above thing is in no way a reference, but a pointer of pointers. It is the context (like function parameters), that gives a type (like a pointer to pointer) the meaning of a reference (in this case a reference to a pointer). But you cannot just go along and call a pointer to a pointer a reference.

Comment: Inteanlly, though a reference is implemented as a pointer to pointer..when you use &...that is what is happening at the address level

Comment: (Just in case you were curious) C++ has its built in "& argument" feature to implement
reference parameters for the programmer.

Comment: @Christian...read the whole article

Comment: The short story is, append an '&' to the type of
a parameter, and the compiler will automatically make the parameter operate by reference
for you.

Comment: Which in the context of the article a reference is **

Comment: @ChrisAaker No! A reference is not implemented as a pointer to pointer, but just as a pointer. A reference to a pointer would be a pointer to a pointer, technically, the same as a reference to an int would be a pointer to an int, technically.

Comment: How else would you implement a reference? not in a language context..but in a memory and data context

Comment: @ChrisAaker I've explained that. In a memory and data (hardware-like, if you want) context, I would implement a reference as a pointer. A reference to a pointer as a pointer to a pointer and a reference to an int as a pointer to an int, but a reference without a type just has no meaning, and it's definitely not a pointer to a pointer, only if it yould refer to a pointer, but then the reference part alone is just a pointer (thouhg, to a pointer), but not pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Wehter it is a pointer to a pointer...or just a pointer..you proved my point that they are related...and not "completely different things" as stated above....in fact you prove my point more than I do as you claim they are the same thing in hardware where as I claim a referecne is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @ChrisAaker I never said they are the same thing (even in hardware). A reference is not a pointer to a pointer, but just a pointer (do you at least notice the lack of a **pointer** in the second term, now after the tenth time?). And specifically in your `new` example the whole term doesn't fit in any way, and neither was it related to the `malloc` example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to do:

```
std::vector<int> scratch(size);
```

But for the record, what you tried should be:

```
int* scratch = new int[size];
delete[] scratch;
```

Note that if `size` is known at compile-time, you also simply do:

```
int scratch[size];
```

### Edit

For an array of pointers to `int`, the desired syntax is:

```
int** scratch = new int*[size];
delete[] scratch;
```

Note that the the pointers inside the array are **not refering to allocated memory** and that you must allocate every pointed `int` before being able to use them.

That is, you may do:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;

scratch[0] = &a;
scratch[1] = &b;
scratch[2] = &a;
scratch[3] = new int(5); // Well, I don't see why anyone would like to do that but if you do, don't forget to also call delete on the pointer when you are done with it.
```

Anyway, unless you have some particular constraints, the most `C++` way of doing things is probably still a `std::vector<int*>` as dealing with pointers of pointers becomes a bit unmaintainable after some levels of indirection.

Comment: @ChrisAaker Your `malloc` example doesn't use an array of pointers either. If that is what you want your `new` example was indeed correct and your `malloc` example was broken.

Comment: O.K. I see any chance you would add info. on how to do pointer to pointers...using malloc...as another EDIT on you answer...Thanks!

Comment: the MOST C++ way is `std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int> >` :)

Comment: @totowtwo: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11. That would rather be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` if anything. Anyway, we don't know about the OP requirements (perhaps the array or the vector **does not own** the pointed integers so a `std::vector<int*>` is good enough in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

`int *scratch = new int[size];
 delete[] scratch;`

or

`std::vector<int> scratch(size);`

or for an array of pointers

```
std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int> > scratch; 
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {     
    scratch.push_back(std::auto_ptr(new int)) 
}
```

Comment: You don't want an array of pointers in your question. You probably don't want an array of pointers in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
int **scratch = new int*[size];
```

How did you come up with this? What about the simple

```
int *scratch = new int[size];
```

The `delete` was used correctly, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  It's:

```
int *scratch = new int[size];
delete [] scratch;
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between an array of pointers and an array of ints?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is:

```
int *scratch = new int[size];
delete[] scratch;
```

In short, for arrays `(T*)malloc(size * sizeof(T))` translates as `new T[size]` and `free(ptr)` into `delete[] ptr`.