# How to use new operator inside overloaded new operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

i am trying to understand about the new operator overloading, in mean while i got a deep confuse about that and my question over here is?

1. How i can use new operator inside my overloaded new operator in both globally and locally.

Regarding global overload i found this link 
[How do I call the original "operator new" if I have overloaded it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134195/how-do-i-call-the-original-operator-new-if-i-have-overloaded-it), but what about my local overloaded new operator. If any one give clarification about my question it will too help full for me.

Along with that i need to know which is the best way to overload new operator either locally or globally (may be its depends on my design) still i need to know for best design and performance purpose. Thank is advance

Answer (score 6):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new - there are examples and explanetions.

E.g.:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    X() { throw std::runtime_error(""); }
    // custom placement new
    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz, bool b) {
        std::cout << "custom placement new called, b = " << b << '\n';
        return ::operator new(sz);
    }
    // custom placement delete
    static void operator delete(void* ptr, bool b)
    {
        std::cout << "custom placement delete called, b = " << b << '\n';
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};
int main() {
   try {
     X* p1 = new (true) X;
   } catch(const std::exception&) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer.

If you want to use new operator inside your overloaded new operator in both globally and locally, then just prefix with `::` (scope resolution) to address to the global new operator.
Ex: `operator new() -> will call your custom local overloaded new operator.`

```
::operator new() -> will call global inbuilt new operator.
```